# Access to Facebook groups without Facebook account?

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups

Is there a way to access the content of Facebook groups without having a Facebook account?

I seem to remember this was possible in the past, but now all I see is a login screen. I thought it was maybe the privacy setting of the specific group I tried to access, but after having tried about a dozen random other groups it seems Facebook has completely closed down the access to their groups for non-Facebook members.

Answer (score 6):

There is no way to access a group without a Facebook account.

> To read a Group, you need:
>
> - any valid access_token if the group is public (i.e. the group's privacy setting is OPEN)
> - user_groups permission for a user's non-public groups
> - friends_groups permission for a user's friend's non-public groups

The specific rules regarding groups and what is required to access them can be [found in the Facebook Developers documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/group/).

Comment: The quote appears to talk about API access, which is not what the question is about.

Answer (score 0):

NO.

You must have a Facebook 'personal profile' to join a Facebook Group.

Answer (score -1):

That's not what the FB 'Privacy Setting fo Groups' says:

'People not logged into Facebook may see the names and descriptions of public and closed groups. They may also see posts in public groups'.

So the Setting say, but I have not been able to make work so far.